# Why numpy.dot() gives incorrect answer for large values?

Tags: numpy, data-science, large-data, dot-product

```
a=list(range(10000))
b=list(range(10000))

result=0
for i,j in zip(a,b):
    result+=i*j
print(result)

print()

import numpy as np

numpy_result=np.dot((np.array(a)),(np.array(b)))
print(numpy_result)

Output

333283335000

-1724114088
```

Comment: Looks like `np.array(a)` has a `np.int32` dtype.  `np.int64` is the default on newer computers and/or python/numpy versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is an overflow issue.

333283335000 is way greater than 2^31 so you need to do the operation in `long long`

```
numpy_result=np.dot(np.array(a, dtype=np.longlong), np.array(b, dtype=np.longlong))
```

> 333283335000